# What is the quickest way to clear an area of tall grass?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

On Minecraft, XBox 360 Edition, I have a 40x40 block area that I plan to build in, except for one small problem; almost all of it is covered in tall grass. What's the quickest way to clear all of this tall grass? NOTE: I would like the actual grass blocks to stay intact

Comment: So no TNT then...

Comment: That's kinda the whole point :P . If I was willing to use TNT the entire biome would have been blown to kingdom come by now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pour a bucket of water down. It will knock the tall grass/flowers/etc off the block.

Comment: That's probably much more time efficient than my method of holding the mouse button then flailing the view wildly until everything is gone

Comment: @RhysW: lol, that tends to be what I do as well :P

Comment: Why was my first reaction "Why not lava?" ? - I'm getting scared of myself. Well, why not Lava? Because Lava flows only 4 blocks away.

Comment: Because I don't want to start a 40x40 fire o.o

Comment: The reason why you don't use lava is because it actually blocks sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use fire, though be careful not to let it go out of control

Answer (score 0):

There could be a handy solution to solving grass problems that contain regular grass but could also work with tall grass. Sheep is the answer. Bring as many as you can and you will also benefit in letting your herds of sheep regain their wool quickly. If you simply want a quick and cheap solution, I would best recommend baby sheep.

Answers for other suggestions.

Water: They are very useful only if you have a flat plain, unlike in real minecraft, where you have slopes that water would likely take paths.

Fire: They could only be so far efficient solutions in heavily grown areas. (lots of tall grass)

Answer (score -1):

Control water by only placing one "block" of it at a time and then when it's covered the desired area, just pick it back up with a bucket.

Comment: This was already stated by @Rapitor 2 years ago.

Comment: While this is similar to the other answer, it does give details that are not explicitly present.  It is quite possible that this would help someone who doesn't understand how to apply the original answer.